# Single opening with multiple doors: "trapdoor" or "trapdoors"

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds, compound-words

Is it "a trapdoor" or "trapdoors" for one opening with two or more doors covering it? One example is the one(s) covering [Black Horse Inn's cellar](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black_Horse_Inn_pub_cellar_trap_door_in_Nuthurst_West_Sussex_England_01.jpg).

Clearly it is plural when there are two or more separate openings each covered by one or more doors, and it is singular when there is one opening covered by one door. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trapdoor) says a trapdoor is "a small door in a ceiling or floor", and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trapdoor) and [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/trapdoor) similarly describe a single door covering a single opening. The title on the Black Horse Inn Cellar example image refers to a "trap door", which is singular but also an open compound word rather than a closed compound word.

I cannot find an official reference disambiguating this, so perhaps either way is correct?

Comment: The door in the image is commonly known as a "bulkhead" door in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm from the Midwest US and have only ever heard "bulkhead" in the context of ships. But the US is a big place, so this could be common in another region.

Comment: @MicahLindstrom There is usually a bulkhead in a car, it's the panel that separates the passenger compartment from the engine compartment.  Usually the steering wheel and the pedals pass though holes in it but are also supported by it.

Comment: Don't trap doors have to open downward?

Comment: Try [cellar doors](https://buymbs.com/p-6025-bilco-classic-series-sloped-wall-primed-steel-basement-door.aspx?vid=1136539&utm_source=Google&utm_medium=Product_CPC&utm_campaign=1136539&gclid=Cj0KCQjwk8b7BRCaARIsAARRTL6PbMmqwSYyJmF4y3yCsi-zrQZldnQsJIZtw8b2jZKn9ZUzVHnTqTQaAjapEALw_wcB)

Comment: @PhilSweet My question was about disambiguating the specific word "trapdoor(s)" in the case of a single opening with multiple doors. I provided one example to illustrate "one opening with multiple doors", but was wondering about the concept in general and not this specific example I randomly found on Wikimedia.

Comment: Try double doors or multi-panel doors for more than two. Some people use double door as a singular to refer to the entire access, and others use double doors to refer to the access and only use double door to refer to one panel of a double. "where's X-ray?" "through the double door/s and to the right."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Trapdoor" works like "door":

If I say "Go through the door to the kitchen", I do not expect you break through the door itself. "Door" = (i) door: a flat piece of wood that blocks a hole. (ii) a door**way**: the hole in the wall blocked by a door.

Thus a trapdoor is both (i) a single door covering a hole (ii) the hole concealed or blocked by one or more doors.

The construction "The door/doors of the trapdoor were locked" is valid.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying it's "trapdoor" for any single opening, and "trapdoors" for multiple openings, regardless of number of doors. Your explanation makes sense and is easy to remember, where trapdoor simply refers to the door**way**.

Comment: Yes that's right. Any trapdoor may have one or more [trap]doors.